# qt creator stops on Linux signal

Tags: linux, qt, signals, qt-creator

I have created a HUP signal handler in linux only C++ app (as per [QT link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/unix-signals.html)) and am working in QT Creator 5.1.  The code compiles and runs fine in QT Creator, but when I send the HUP signal from a command line, QT Creator stops with a popup:

**"The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system"** along with HUP signal information.

If I click the CONTINUE button on the debug panel I see my qDebug statements printout from my HUP signal handler in my code.  My question is, is this normal behaviour?  Why is QT Creator trapping HUP and stopping my code, when my code is properly handling the HUP signal?

Comment: Maybe Qt Creator ain't like stuff coming from the outside of the box, try your application directly from a console and not from Qt

Comment: yep - that works ok.  I was hoping there was a setting somewhere in QT Creator make it ignore signals...

Comment: IIRC it's not Qt Creator, but the debugger doing it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just uncheck the box "Show a message box when receiving a signal" in Tools -> Options... -> Debugger -> GDB.

P.S. Of course that concerns only a popup window in Qt Creator, but the main part is a debugger. If you want gdb not to catch a signal but pass it to your program, you need to give gdb a command like the following: `handle SIGHUP pass nostop noprint` (see Window -> Views -> Debugger Log or Tools -> Options... -> Debugger -> Locals & Expressions -> Debugging Helper Customization (like the image below for the SIGINT signal)).

[image]